# VBScript: Search remote registry to return SID and mapped share drives

Tags: vbscript, registry

I'm looking for some help creating script that would search for username in
 *ProfileImagePath* string in Remote_Machine\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21* 
and would get parent directory-the SID S-1-5-21*, store it in memory and later use it to output keys under 
Remote_machine\HKEY_USERS*SID*\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2.

I was only able to find script:

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputerName = InputBox("Please input PC name:","")'objNetwork.ComputerName
strLogonUser = objNetwork.UserName

Domaccount = trim(cstr(InputBox("Please input Domain User Account:","Type User_
Account")))
strDomain = "Dom"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputerName & "\root\cimv2")

Set objAccount = objWMIService.Get ("Win32_UserAccount.Name='" & Domaccount &_
"',Domain='" & strDomain & "'")
Wscript.Echo objAccount.SID
```

but that one does not work all the time - I get *SWbemServicesEx: Not found*
and I think it uses different method than search. Moreover it does only first part of my request.
Can anyone help a brother out? :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to have understood your exact problem, anyway  this hotfix released by Microsoft has been useful to me in a similar situation:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2465990